# Grant Oracle account read permission

Tags: oracle11g

I do MSSQL administration and recently got involved with Oracle.  So my Oracle admin skills obviously is weak.  I have a question regarding Oracle account and permissions.  Say I have the following two schemas (users) created on an Oracle 12c instance – John and Dave.  How do I grant “John” SELECT privilege to all the tables under the “Dave” schema?  If possible, can you list the steps or better yet, the SQL commands.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

FOR x IN (SELECT table_name FROM all_tables where owner='DAVE')
LOOP
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT ON ' || x.table_name || ' TO JOHN';
END LOOP;

Comment: Though I believe this will do non-materialized views as well; not just "tables"

Comment: You are most Welcome.
As i also have just shifted from MSSQL to Oracle, these things were completely new to me as well